# Error en NSDateFormatter

Tags: swift2

Tengo un pequeño error en `NSDateFormatter()`. Cuando arranco la aplicación lo carga y me muestra la fecha pero cuando cambio de mes y vuelve a pasar por la función me da un error.

```
func supplementaryView(shouldDisplayOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool {
       let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date2 = dateformatter.stringFromDate(dayView.date.convertedDate()!)

        let date_Array = ["2016-02-10","2016-02-11","2016-02-12","2016-01-11"]     
        for(var i=0;i<date_Array.count;i++)
        {
            if(date2==date_Array[i])
            {
                return true
            }
        return false
    }
```

El problema esta en `dateformatter.stringFromDate(dayView.date.convertedDate()!)` Ya que estas convirtiendo a un String.

El error está solucionado. El problema viene por el dayView ya que hay que especificarle el Día , Mes y año. Dejo el código arreglado.

```
func supplementaryView(shouldDisplayOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool {
        let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date_Array = [[2016,02,10],[2016,02,11],[2016,02,12],[2016,01,11]]
        for(var i=0;i<date_Array.count;i++)
        {
        if let date = dayView.date {
            if(date.day == date_Array[i][2] && date.month == date_Array[i][1] && date.year == date_Array[i][0]) {
                return true
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
        return false
    }
```

Lo que hacemos es especificar el día , mes y año y ya no sale el error, ya que cuando vuelve a pasar por el for if ya no dará error.

Comment: lo ideal sería que dejaras el código que no funciona junto al código que funciona por si a alguien le ocurre lo mismo. Y ya de paso explicar qué pasaba al no pasarle la fecha correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente el problema es que `dayView.date.convertedDate()` es nil, ya que es un `Optional` y no has verificado si existe antes de utilizarlo.
Podrías modificar el código de la siguiente manera:

```
func supplementaryView(shouldDisplayOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool {
    let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    guard let converted = dayView.date.convertedDate() else {
        return false
    }
    let date2 = dateformatter.stringFromDate(converted)

    let date_Array = ["2016-02-10","2016-02-11","2016-02-12","2016-01-11"]
    let date_Array2 = ["2016-02-20","2016-02-21","2016-02-22","2016-01-22"]


    for(var i=0;i<date_Array.count;i++)
    {
        if(date2==date_Array[i])
        {
            color = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
            return true
        }

        if(date2==date_Array2[i])
        {
            color = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
            return true
        }

    }
    return false
  }
}
```

De esta manera, si `dayView.date.convertedDate()` existe continuará sin problema, si no, devolverá `false` y no continuará la función.

Comment: Sigue Partiendo en el guard let converted

Comment: Podrías poner qué hay en `DayView`, `date` y `convertedDate()`? Es posible que haya algún otro `Optional` que haga que pete...

Comment: La función converted date ` public func convertedDate() -> NSDate? {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let comps = Manager.componentsForDate(NSDate())
        
        comps.year = year
        comps.month = month
        comps.weekOfMonth = week
        comps.day = day
        
        return calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)
    }
`

Comment: Quizás `Manager.componentsForDate()` es la que te esté fallando. Aún así, el problema es que algo de una de esas funciones es nil y por tanto debes asegurarte de que cualquier `Optional` existe.

Comment: No, mira el la función en CVCalendar pero no tiene ningún optional [Encale CVCalendar](http://https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar/blob/master/CVCalendar/CVCalendarManager.swift)

Comment: Ahora no sé como funciona exactamente `CVCalendar` pero te puedo asegurar que ese error es porque un `Optional` no existe y está intentando utilizarlo.